# Bubble Sort Is only sorting my numbers halfway why? JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bubble-sort

I am sorting 30 random generated number by a bubble sort for some reason they get sorted from 15 to 29 but they are still not sorted from 0 to 14. It is like the sorting stops for some reason. My attempt was to change i++ to i-- but didn't really work. Does anyone know what's wrong in the loop thank you

JavaScript:

```
arr =new Array(30);
var length = arr.length;

function randomNumber(min,max){
    var min = Math.ceil(min);
    var max = Math.floor (max);
        for(var i = 0; i<length; i++){
            arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min)) + min;
            document.write("Number " +(i)+ " : "   +arr[i] + "<br >"); }

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
      for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { 
        
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]){
          //Swap the numbers
         var tmp = arr[j]; 
          arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; 
        arr[j + 1] = tmp; //Replace adjacent number with current number       
        //[[arr[j],arr[j+1]] = [arr[j+1], arr[j]]];} }
      document.write("Number " +(i)+ " : "   +arr[i] + "<br >"); }
    return arr;}
```

HTML calling the method:

```
                            <script> 
                                  
                                randomNumber(1,1000);

                            </script>
```

Below are outputs of the code:

[Random Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26bf1.png)

[Bubble Sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SW8j3.png)

Comment: Just an FYI, for people that develop primarily with Javascript, I think it's fair to say that seeing the curly brackets `{` broken onto new lines is like nails on a chalkboard and makes it more difficult to read.

Comment: That's how my lecturers always taught us to do it. It's just preference

Comment: I understand. I'm just letting you know that professionally, most Javascript developers do not break the brackets on new lines – take a look at almost any open source Javascript project – and that you're more likely to get help when its easier for your target audience to read it.

Comment: Save a little time by subtracting 1 from the first condition, and -i-1 on the second condition.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't print out the array within the loop. The sorting process isn't finished yet. Move the write command after it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { 
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
            var tmp = arr[j]; 
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1]; 
            arr[j + 1] = tmp; 
        }
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    document.write("Number " +(i)+ " : "   +arr[i] + "<br >");     
}
```

It should give you the right answer.